# Windows 10 "Create New Task" drop-down menu

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

Ever since updating to Windows 10 in July, Task Manager no longer records the path of applications launched via Task Manager. The dialouge box below is accessed by selecting "Run new task" from the File menu in Windows Task Manager. As you can see, that drop-down menu is empty, and it has been that way ever since I updated to Windows 10. Can anyone offer some suggestions for fixing or diagnosing this?

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows 10 v1511, even after a reboot.  Have you ever actually typed anything into that box and successfully started it as a task (since updating to Windows 10)? If not, that's why there's nothing in the list.

Comment: And it works fine on every other Windows 10 computer I've tried. I use the Create new task function quite often, which is why I'd like to find a way to get the history drop-down to working again.